# "Vaishnav and Pizzas" challenge

Tags: c++, performance, programming-challenge

I am trying to solve the below mentioned problem from [HackerEarth](http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/vaishnav-and-pizzas/).

Although the results are fine, the code takes extraordinarily long time to run execute. I am pretty sure the problem is because of the nested loops, and I am working on it.

I would like to know:

1. How can this code be optimized to run within 1 sec?
2. What are the general programming principles to optimize your execution time, say while writing embedded applications with time constraints.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   int testcase;
   cin >> testcase;
   int Number[10000];
   for(int i = 0; i < testcase ; i++)
   {
      cin >> Number[i];
   }

   float numerator, denominator,result;
   //float myArr[100000];
   vector<float> myArr;

   for(int i = 0; i < testcase ; i++)
   {
      for(int j = 1; j <= Number[i] ; j++)
      {
         for(int k = 1; k <= Number[i] ; k++)
         {
            numerator = j;
            denominator = k;
            //cout << numerator << denominator << endl;
            if(numerator < denominator)
            {
               result = numerator/denominator;
               //cout << result << endl;
               bool found = false;
               for(int x=0; x < myArr.size() ; x++)
               {
                  if(result == myArr[x])
                  {
                     found = true;
                     break;
                  }
               }
               if(found == false)
               {
                  myArr.push_back(result);
               }
            }
         }
      }
      cout << myArr.size() << endl;
      myArr.clear();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the execution time amounts to O(n^3) because of the nested loops. A brute force approach cannot be healed; you need to change the algorithm.

A given denominator `Q` produces exactly [`phi(Q)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) rational numbers, so the problem boils down to calculating $$ \sum \phi (k) $$

There are many approaches for doing that. For the small numbers (according to constraints, less than 10000) I'd recommend a straightforward use of multiplicative property. A precomputed table of primes may also help.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I did check on the phi(n) formula to get the result, but still the execution time is above 1 sec. But definitely lot of improvement in execution time is seen compared to my earlier solution :)

Answer (score 1):

There are few details that you can improve in your code to make it better, code quality wise. So I think it is also worth commenting on those.

**Naming**:

C++ variables are usually named using `camelCase` (some prefer `snake_case`). So `testcase` should be renamed to `testCase` or `test_case`. `Number` is an array, so it should use a plural name, since it doesn't refer to a single object. `numbers` would be a better name.

**main()**:

You are not using `argc` and `argv` from `main()`, so redeclare the function to take no arguments:

```
int main() { }
```

Most compilers emit warnings about unused variables. I always compile with warnings as errors, so that yielded an error for me.

Also, the `return 0;` at the end is not strictly necessary in C++. It will be implicitly added by the compiler if omitted.

**Performance/memory/etc**:

The main bottleneck in your program is, no doubt, the three nested for() loops. But there is another sub-optimal point in there. You are calling `myArr.push_back(result);` inside the innermost loop. `std::vector::push_back()` will reallocate and copy once it reaches its maximum capacity. This might be happening many times inside the loops, slowing them even more. Ideally, you should call [`std::vector::reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) just before entering the first loop. If you don't know the exact size in advance, make an educated guess, profile and refine. Pre-allocating the storage beforehand is ought to improve performance.

`int Number[10000];` is a pretty big array to be declared on the program stack. Such big objects should be allocated on the heap.

`using namespace std` is OK inside a `.cpp` file, but should never appear on a header file.